# unlock non standard script

Tags: script, raw-transaction

i transferred some coins to a testnet address `2MwP5KwNRsQV5cf3T7VcFU4Vhj2LcUeMiLM` with a locking script just to play with scripts. the locking script is `OP_1 OP_2 OP_ADD` (always evaluates to true).

how can i get the coins from this address? (not for the coins, but to learn bitcoin script)

the address was made with `bitcoin-cli decodescript 515293`

```
...
  "p2sh-segwit": "2MwP5KwNRsQV5cf3T7VcFU4Vhj2LcUeMiLM"
...
```

(btw i know you can now claim the 1000 test sat, but please tell me how)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [section about spending a p2sh](https://github.com/BlockchainCommons/Learning-Bitcoin-from-the-Command-Line/blob/master/10_6_Spending_a_P2SH_Transaction.md) in the learning bitcoin from the command line course. It mainly refers back to previous sections explaining the single steps but I think your question is about the variables that you need to put into the signing-transactions-command.

In the example it says:

> [...] signing requires entering extra information for the (1)
> scriptPubKey; (2) the redeemScript; and (3) any required private keys.
>
> Here's the example of doing so for that P2SH-embedded multisig in
> §6.2: `$ bitcoin-cli -named signrawtransactionwithkey hexstring=$rawtxhex prevtxs='''[ { "txid": "'$utxo_txid'", "vout": '$utxo_vout', "scriptPubKey": "'$utxo_spk'", "redeemScript": "'$redeem_script'" } ]''' privkeys='["cNPhhGjatADfhLD5gLfrR2JZKDE99Mn26NCbERsvnr24B3PcSbtR"]'`
>
> With any other sort of P2SH you're going to be including a different
> redeemscript, but otherwise the practice is exactly the same.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

The scriptPubkey above is a P2WSH nested in P2SH.

In order to unlock this coin:

- Put P2WSH payload into input scriptSig.`00204a3babc5f8f8f5f67b6331c18931e6f198b6cf576b0f3747314d11dedddf97c5`
- Put P2WSH's witnessScript(redeemScript) into input witness. `515293`

https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#P2WSH_nested_in_BIP16_P2SH